# State is undefined when used in react router link inside useMemo hook

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-table

I am using react router to navigate to another page and pass state to that page using this inside useMemo

```
 const columns = React.useMemo(
    () => [
      {
        Header: "Actions",
        id: "actions",
        Cell: (tableProps) => {
          return (
            <>
               <Link
                to={{
                  pathname: "list-table/list-table-edit",
                  state: { selectedRow },
                }}
              > 
              <span
                style={{
                  cursor: "pointer",
                  color: "grey",
                  textDecoration: "underline",
                }}
                onClick={(event) => {
                  
                  setSelectedID(tableProps.row.original.asset_ID);
                }}
              >
                <Tooltip title="Edit Row">
                  <EditButton aria-label="edit">
                    <CreateIcon fontSize="small" />
                  </EditButton>
                </Tooltip>
              </span>
               </Link> 
            </>
          );
        },
      },
      ...MakeTableColumns,
    ],
    [selectedRow]
  );
```

My state are declared like this

```
  const [selectedID, setSelectedID] = useState();
  const selectedRow = oriData.find((row) => row.asset_ID === selectedID);
```

when user click `Edit`, it will set row ID to `selectedID` and `selectedRow` finds row values and pass to `list-table-edit` page.
however, when I console.log `props.location.state` from `list-table-edit` , it's showing `undefined`. When I take out `<Link> ..`  outside of `useMemo` and give a status id, it is working fine, I think it's something wrong with `useMemo`.
If anyone could help, I would be very much appreciated, thanks

> **Updated**

Now I change from `state: { selectedRow }` to `state: { tableProps.row.original }` and pass to another page and it works without passing the state. I could have already had the selected row value by calling `tableProps.row.original`.

Comment: Have you validated that `selectedRow` is defined in the component with the link? Can you provide a more complete code example? Provide code for both the linking component and the linked-to component? What version of react-router/react-router-dom are you using?

Comment: I am adding it in `useMemo` hook for making tables, I took it outside of `useMemo` hook and it's working, seems like it's with useMemo hook. I will update my question.

Comment: So is `selectedRow` in the functional component body and recomputed each render cycle? I think we still need more context. More of this component's code, and the code for the component trying to access route state. It still isn't confirmed if `selectedRow` has the value you want when the link is clicked.

Comment: It could be because `selectedRow` doesn't have the value when link is clicked inside `useMemo`, this is the full code of the component if you wanna check.
https://codesandbox.io/s/confident-dirac-jhqp0?file=/src/App.js
 I declared those states on top.

Comment: If you logged `selectedRow` in the memo hook before returning the column array do you see it updating with the updates to state in the main component?

Comment: I commented out Link tag, and when I console.log selectedRow `inside` useMemo, the `first time after I clicked edit`, it shows `undefined` but `after first time` it shows value. When I console log it `outside` of useMemo it print value just after edit button is clicked. I think I need to figure out why first time is showing undefined inside useMemo after edit is clicked.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why are you memoizing UI elements? It almost a guarantee to have stale enclosures. It doesn't really appear as though `selectedRow` is part of any react state so I think you also lose some guarantees there with the react lifecycle.

Comment: I am using `react-table` to make tables and it requires the column and data values to be memorized using useMemo hook. I guess I will just try to work on the same page using components instead of going new page along with data, thanks for the help !
https://react-table.tanstack.com/docs/api/useTable

Comment: I found solution. In my code, I already had the selected value by calling this `tableProps.row.original`, so I can pass that value inside `Link` to another page without using state. I was dumb enough and keep looking to use state in useMemo and pass through `Link`

Answer (score 0):

```
<Link to={{ pathname: '/list-table/list-table-edit', state: { record: selectedRow} }}>My route</Link>
```

Comment: It's still `undefined` showing `state: {record: undefined}`